# Finding all $x, y$ natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Find all natural numbers $x$ and $y$ such that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}}{\sqrt[3]{x^2 - y^2}} \in \mathbb{N}.
$$

My approach:
$x>y$ because otherwise the radical would be negative and we can see that $(1;0)$ is a solution to the equation. How do we prove that there are other solutions?

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200210/the-diophantine-equation-x2-y2-z3?noredirect=1).

Comment: That's a cube root in the denominator, not a square root. So you can't rule out $x<y$ by saying it's not well-defined. (You _can_ rule it out by saying that it would be negative, whereas $\Bbb N$ contains only positive numbers.)

Comment: What contest is this from? Anyway it is similar to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4799031) of yours.

Comment: @Sil  It’s from a gazette from Romania that prepares you for contests. This is the original problem from the gazette. The one I posted was inspired from the original problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
k=\frac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}}{\sqrt[3]{x^2 - y^2}}
$$
for some positive integer $k$. Then
$$
(x^2-y^2)^2k^6=(x+2\sqrt{xy}+y)^3.
$$
We can see the expanded right hand side is of the form $m+n\sqrt{xy}$ for some integers $m,n$, and therefore $\sqrt{xy}$ is a rational number. It's not hard to see that this implies that $\sqrt{xy}$ is an integer, so $xy$ is a perfect square. Thus we can assume $x=la^2,y=lb^2$ where $(a,b)=1$ and $l$ is a positive integer. Plugging back to the original equation and raising both sides to sixth power we get
$$
k^6=\frac{l^3(a + b)^6}{l^4(a^4 - b^4)^2} = \frac{(a + b)^4}{l(a-b)^2(a^2+b^2)^2}.
$$
Now we see that $l$ is a square of a rational number, but since it $l$ is an integer, it must actually be a perfect square. This means $x$ and $y$ are both perfect squares.

So WLOG assume $x=a^2,y=b^2$ and the equation becomes
$$
k^3=\frac{(a+b)^2}{(a-b)(a^2+b^2)}.
$$
In particular $a^2+b^2$ divides $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$. Hence $a^2+b^2$ divides $2ab$, but since both values are positive, we have $a^2+b^2\leq 2ab$, i.e. $(a-b)^2\leq 0$ and thus $a=b$, impossible. So there is no solution in positive integers.

If we allow $y=0$ then the problem simplifies to $k^6x=1$ which leads to $x=1$.